# Is there in R a way of modifying the input variables of a self-made function?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm starting with R, so i'm doing some small projects that could help me understand how this programming language works.

For that, I'm creating a function that enables me to delete columns and lines of a data frame with different kinds of inputs. When trying to implement the functions, it seems that they don't change the input variables after the execution.

```
rm_row <- function(data_input, rm_val){
  #rm can be either a vector of trues and falses(true for delete) or a vector that includes the number of the lines you must remove
  if (typeof(rm_val) == "double" | typeof(rm_val) == "logical"){
    data_input <- data_input[-rm_val,]
  }
  else {
    print(typeof(rm_val))
    print("Invalid type of value")
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Change `data_input <- data_input[-rm_val,]` to `data_input[-rm_val,]`, then call your function as `newData <- rm_row(myData, 1:3)`

Comment: A function should always have a return value, always. The only exception to that is if the function throws an error exception. I would argue, your function should throw an error for wrong input types. You might be interested in `help("stopifnot")` which is the common way to assert correct input and throw an error if the assertion fails. If you insist on your approach, at least use `warning` instead of printing something and create a sensible return value in your `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `return()` at the end of the function. Try this:

```
rm_row <- function(data_input, rm_val){
  #rm can be either a vector of trues and falses(true for delete) or a vector that includes the number of the lines you must remove
  if (typeof(rm_val) == "double" | typeof(rm_val) == "logical"){
    data_input <- data_input[-rm_val,]
  }
  else {
    print(typeof(rm_val))
    print("Invalid type of value")
  }
  return(data_input)
}
```